# Adding Java EE into existing Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, java-ee-7, eclipse-mars

I wanted to add Java EE 7 into Eclipse Mars, but don't know how. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

**one way;**

download [javaee-api-7.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar)

copy it any location on your computer (say /path/to/javaee/javaee-api-7.0.jar)

then, from eclipse menu

```
window > preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add > Basic > J2EE Runtime Library > Next > (Select /path/to/javaee) > Finish
```

then, add this runtime to your (needed) projects' classpath  by

```
right click on project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > Server Runtime > Next > (Select) J2EE Runtime Library > Finish
```

**another way;**

you can download a java ee 7 compatible server (listed [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html)) adapter from eclipse marketplace and its runtime,

then, add this runtime to your (needed) projects' classpath by

```
right click on project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Library > Server Runtime > Next > (Select) (downloaded server) > Finish
```

Comment: But I don't have the Server tab in preferences.

Comment: don't have it either

Comment: please make sure you downloaded the "Eclipse For Java EE Developers" form [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars1)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link..

> Open the  Opens the Installed JREs preference page Java > Installed
>   JREs preference page. Select the Add... button. The Add JRE wizard
>   opens. You will have to select the type of JRE you would like to
>   create: Standard VM - You will select a folder where the JRE is
>   installed. The details of the JRE will be determined by scanning the
>   location. You can further customize the JRE install, specifying vm
>   arguments, source attachments, etc. Standard VM 1.x.x - Same options
>   as a standard VM install, but the install is customized to handle the
>   1.x.x install Execution Environment Description - You will select an execution environment (EE) file that describes all the details
>   required to set up the JRE. You will be able to customize some aspects
>   of the install.

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-installed_jres.htm